# Every sequence of disjoint elements in an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space converges weakly to zero

Tags: functional-analysis

> Prove that every sequence of disjoint elements in an orthonormal basis $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ of a Hilbert space $H$ converges weakly to zero.

Here is what I tried: In that basis any linear operator $f$ can be written as a map $\sum a_j e_j \mapsto \sum b_j a_j$. I guess most of  the $b_j$'s must be zero, but have no argument. If $J$ was all integer indexes, I could say that as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ all $b_\alpha$'s would be zero and we would have weak convergence, but this argument doesn't work since I don't know how many $b_j$'s are $0$ and $J$ could be non-enumerable.

Does anyone have an working proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(e_{\alpha_n})$ is  a sequence in the orthonormal set then $\sum |\langle x, e_{\alpha_n} \rangle|^{2} \leq \|x\|^{2} <\infty$ for any $x$. It follows that $\langle x, e_{\alpha_n} \rangle \to 0$. By Reisz Theorem any continuous linear functional is of the form $y \to \langle y, x \rangle$ for some $x$. Hence $(e_{\alpha_n}) \to 0$ weakly.